# Get value from control in the same control as the button is located

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a StackPanel, some Expanders, some textboxes and some buttons.

For example I have the following structure:

```
StackPanel
  Expander 1
    TextBox 1
    Button 1 
  Expander 2
    TextBox 2
    Button 2
  Expander 3
    TextBox 3
    Button 3
```

How can i get the textbox.Text from the Expander where the Button is clicked?

For example i click Button 2 and I want to get TextBox 2 in Expander 2.
All the controls are added programmatically instead of the StackPanel.

Is there something like a event? I don't know the way to get the textbox when a button is clicked in the same expander.

I want 2 Methods to save my Expander Header and its content (a textbox value for example).

the 1st method is by right clicking the Expander's Header which will transform the Header into a TextBox so i can edit the text. By clicking ENTER it will save the TextBox.Text into TextBlock. Which works fine. But i can't use the same code for a Button.

```
Expander editable_expander;  // Expander sender  from Expander_MouseRightButtonDown

    private void Expander_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = sender as Expander;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Text = ex.Header.ToString();
        tb.KeyUp += TextBox_KeyUp;
        ex.Header = tb;
        editable_expander = ex;
    }

    private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Edit Columnname of selected Column when Enter pressed
        if (e.Key != Key.Enter) return;

        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        e.Handled = true;


        string old_expander_name = editable_expander.Name.ToString();
        string old_column_name = old_expander_name.Split('_')[0];

        int length = 0;
        string type = "";

        if(OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                Grid grid = editable_expander.Content as Grid;
                List<StackPanel> stackpanel = grid.Children.OfType<StackPanel>().ToList();
                for(int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    StackPanel sp = stackpanel[i];
                    List<TextBox> textbox = sp.Children.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
                    for(int j = 0; j < textbox.Count; j++)
                    {
                        TextBox tb1 = textbox[j];
                        length = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);
                    }
                    List<ComboBox> combobox = sp.Children.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList();
                    for(int k = 0; k < combobox.Count; k++)
                    {
                        ComboBox cb = combobox[k];
                        type = cb.Text;
                    }
                }

                string query = "ALTER TABLE " + editable_expander.Tag + " CHANGE " + old_column_name + " " +  tb.Text + " " + type + "(" + length + ")";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        editable_expander.Header = tb.Text;
    }
```

Comment: I want 2 methods to save. 1 is right clicking expander headers this will transform the header into textbox. when enter is pressed it will save and will change back to TextBlock. i will add this method in my topic. But i guess i cant make this again with the button click event because im working with textbox event

Comment: Google some stuff... like "WPF get parent control" and "WPF get specific child control"

Comment: I think you want to look at making a viewmodel for each Expander information. That way that object can update the local info under the Expander

Comment: @kenny im working with Code-Behind because the whole project is written in code-behind. MVVM is hard for me to learn and to transform the whole project in mvvm while take years for me. Im not much familar with viewmodels etc. because I don't understand it for now.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this in MVVM:

Xaml style:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="{Binding SomeText}" MinWidth="100">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}" MinWidth="100"/>
                    <Button MaxWidth="150" Content="ClickMeToGetYourText" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What you've got here is: List of controls: controls are placed in `StackPanel`, each control have: `Expander` with SomeText as header, then in it, there is also  `TextBox` with same text, and button which you can click. `Button` have command, in which you would get you'r text.

Now some code in C#:

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ExpanderData> List { set; get; } = new ObservableCollection<ExpanderData>();
    private ICommand _buttonClickedCommand;
    public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_buttonClickedCommand == null)
            {
                _buttonClickedCommand = new RelayCommand(p => ButtonClicked(p));
            }
            return _buttonClickedCommand;
        }
    }

    public void ButtonClicked(Object o)
    {
        var expanderData = (ExpanderData)o;
        var textThatYouWantedToHaveOnButtonClicked = expanderData.SomeText; 
    } 
}
```

You have here list, from which you will create your expanders. `Command` which will allow you to do something on `ButtonClicked`, and method that will fire on `ButtonClicked` event.

Now, how looks the ExpanderData class:

```
public class ExpanderData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _someText;

    public string SomeText
    {
        set
        {
            _someText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get
        {
            return _someText;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
Here you have your Text that is assign to each of your Expander/TextBox, and event that will fire if you want to update your text from code behind.
```

And RelayCommand implementation, which allows you to binding Commands

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        this._canExecute = p => true;
        this._execute = execute;
    }
    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
    {
        this._canExecute = canExecute;
        this._execute = execute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

And this is how you can add VM to your view:

```
var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.List.Add(new ExpanderData() { SomeText = "Text1" });
vm.List.Add(new ExpanderData() { SomeText = "Text2" });
vm.List.Add(new ExpanderData() { SomeText = "Text3" });
vm.List.Add(new ExpanderData() { SomeText = "Text4" });

this.DataContext = vm;
```

Or, if you still want some dirty way:

```
private void ButtonClicked(Object sender, ...) 
{
    var yourTextBox = ((Panel)((Button)sender).Parent).Children.OfType<TextBox>().First();
    var yourText = yourTextBox.Text;
}
```